# Telerik, how to preserve a custom colorization when disabling a control?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, telerik

I have a `RadSplitButton` with the `VisualStudio2012Dark` theme applied, and I've set the borders to a yellowed color through the `Edit UI elements` design menu:

[image]

The problem is that when I disable the control setting the `Enabled` property to `False`, it totally changes the colorization and it provokes a very bad visual effect on my application:

[image]

I could specify what colors to use when the control is disabled?.

Comment: All the Disabled colors seem to be pre-set and not something you can change.  They appear to be assigned by theme, so when you modify many UI Elements you can get really bad results like the invisible button text.

Comment: you can also set `RadSplitBitton.RootElement.UseDefaultDisabledPaint` to false but it basically uses no Theme so the control is painted as ControlDefault giving no clue it is disabled.

Comment: When UseDefaultDisabledPaint is set to false, one can define how the Disabled state of the control will look in the theme - just add s .Disabled state and theme it as you see fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Plutonix said in his comment, disabled colors are pre-set, however they can be modified with Telerik Style Builder (see my update below). A different approach could be to place the control behind a transparent panel and set it visible or not visible to make your radSplitButton accessible or not accessible. This method obviously does not affect the colors of your control.
Since you have used also a c# tag, I prefer to give this to you in c#:

add this class to your project:

```
class Plexiglass : Control
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Parent != null)
        {
            Bitmap plexiCover = new Bitmap(Parent.Width, Parent.Height);
            foreach (Control c in Parent.Controls)
                if (c.Bounds.IntersectsWith(this.Bounds) & c != this)
                    c.DrawToBitmap(plexiCover, c.Bounds);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(plexiCover, -Left, -Top);
            plexiCover.Dispose();
        }
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 0, 0)), Bounds);
    }
}
```

compile the project, add the Plexiglass control from your tool box to the form, drag it on the RadsplitButton and size it properly. You can then set the Plexiglass control visibility to false in your form load event and manage the visibility of the Plexiglass control to make your splitButton  accessible or not accessible. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dr0Ohc8D2d8&feature=youtu.be) is the final result and [here](http://www.speedyshare.com/fKAeN/TelerikWinFormsApp2.rar) is the demo project.  Thanks to IntelOrca for the snippet.

**Update**
Alternatively you can explore possible solution to change the preset colors using the [Visual Style Builder](http://www.telerik.com/winforms/visual-style-builder). I have newer used it but from this [video](http://tv.telerik.com/watch/winforms/visualstylebuilder/styling-basics-with-visual-style-builder-winforms) looks like you can change many control colors and relevant behavior. You can access the tool as following: "Start menu (Start Programs Telerik RadControls for WinForms Qx 201x Tools)".
Once you have loaded the RadSplitButton in the tool, add the status "Disabled" in the element state (top right panel) and apply to it the same colors you have in normal state. That should work but as I said I have never used it so I am not sure of the procedure, however it looks very powerful and will avoid you to have to go trough all the method and properties of the control manually.

Comment: I'm not sure of that, the property `RadSplitButton.DropDownButtonElement.UseDefaultDisabledPaint` says: `Gets or sets whether the item should use the default way for painting the item when disabled (making it gray) or whether the disabled appearance should be controlled by the theme.` but I don't know what to do with that it does not take any effect, I've reasons like that to think that this kind of "disabled-customization" is possible but is "hidden" on the control or its childrens, are too much properties and methods to investigate its functionality one by one. thanks for your answer!

Comment: I understand your dilemma. In asp you can   override the control css but in winform is a different story this is way I suggested a way around it. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for accept the answer late, really is a very nice trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution while I can't find a more efficient solution:

```
    With Me.RadSplitButton1
        .DropDownButtonElement.ShouldHandleMouseInput = False
        .DropDownButtonElement.ActionButton.ShouldHandleMouseInput = False
        .DropDownButtonElement.ArrowButton.ShouldHandleMouseInput = False
         .Cursor = Cursors.No
    End With
```

That disables mouse input on the control but just only do that. it is "half-disabled" without loosing the current colorization.